# Ubuntu, ruby 2, rails 4

Tags: linux, ubuntu, ubuntu-10.04, ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm trying to setup a server, which has Ubuntu 10.04 LTS, Ruby 2.0.0-p0 and Rails 4 beta1. I can get everything installed but rails 4 has a slight error and I'd like to get someones opinion. When I do 'gem install rails --version 4.0.0.beta1 --no-ri --no-rdoc' I get the below error.

> rdoc's executable "rdoc" conflicts with /usr/local/bin/rdoc
>
> Overwrite the executable? [yN]

If I say 'N' then I get the below error ans quits the installation:

```
ERROR:  Error installing rails:
    "rdoc" from rdoc conflicts with /usr/local/bin/rdoc
```

If I say 'y' I then get:

```
rdoc's executable "ri" conflicts with /usr/local/bin/ri
Overwrite the executable? [yN]
```

If I say 'N' it will quit again but if I say 'Y' it will continue with the installation.

By saying 'y' to the 2 above options is this effecting something else? Also, I thought the '--no-ri --no-rdoc' options would not install when included?